# Maven surefire and JDK 11

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin, java-11

I'm trying to get Maven surefire to run under JDK 11 but I keep getting these errors:

1. If I set `reuseForks` to true:

> ```
>   Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
>   Process Exit Code: 1
>   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:670)
>   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
>   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
> ```

2. If I set it to false:

> ```
> Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-   plugin:3.0.0-M1:test
> failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.StartupReportConfiguration
> ```

I've found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1534) and [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-issues/201811.mbox/%3CJIRA.13199325.1542632109000.386195.1542632280042@Atlassian.JIRA%3E) link that describe the same problem but they don't have any solution.

For replication of this bug I created [this git repo](https://github.com/o0oGnas/test)

Comment: Have you tried older versions of the surefire plugin, e.g. 2.21.0?

Comment: @gjoranv Yes I have, same problem on 2.21.0

Comment: For some reason, the `module-info` class is interfering with the test. I've removed it and the test works fine. Probably the plugin is not ready for modular projects yet? Also there is an issue with the module itself (due to wrong openjfx-monocle dependencies probably).

Answer (score 15):

Seems like while using a modular project to `test`, you need to have `forkCount` set as `0` :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount> <!-- changed this to 0 -->
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <!-- <threadCount>1</threadCount> --> <!-- shall be used with 'parallel' -->
        <printSummary>true</printSummary>
        <!-- <skipTests>false</skipTests> --> <!-- defaults to false -->

        <!-- run test in headless mode -->
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <glass.platform>Monocle</glass.platform>
            <monocle.platform>Headless</monocle.platform>
            <prism.order>d3d</prism.order>
        </systemPropertyVariables>

        <argLine>
            --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Quoting [from this article](https://medium.com/criciumadev/its-time-migrating-to-java-11-5eb3868354f9)

> When `module-info.java` is present and fork process is *enabled*, surefire
>   creates a *mixed* classpath with modules and unnamed modules causing
>   module visibility issues and preventing the application to start.

---

***Note***: Disabling the `forkCount` and `reuseForks` configuration parameters, results in `org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException` being thrown, similar to the one reported in [SUREFIRE-1528](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE/issues/SUREFIRE-1528?filter=allopenissues).

If this could help the developers at Maven community, the execution dump from the same run reads the following:

```
# Created at 2018-11-23T09:31:53.631
Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. Stream 'Error occurred during initialization of boot layer'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream stdin corrupted. Expected comma after third character in command 'Error occurred during initialization of boot layer'.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient$OperationalData.<init>(ForkClient.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.processLine(ForkClient.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.consumeLine(ForkClient.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

[Here is the line of code in the source repository.](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/booterclient/output/ForkClient.java#L507)

Comment: Though in my understanding this would result in the tests being run using the classpath and not the modulepath.

Comment: So this mean parallel maven execution is impossible? Because `-T1C` and `forkCount` 0 can't be combined.

Comment: Found https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/, which fixes the multithreaded issue.

Comment: @Dormouse, how does implementing the suggestions in the post address the multithreaded issue?  I don't see any references to threading.

Comment: It was the `--illegal-access=permit`, that Cesar so eloquently turned into an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651001/883603), which I seem to have been too lazy for.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution here:

https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/

I had to add.

```
<argLine>
    --illegal-access=permit
</argLine>
```

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This did not work for me on a spring-boot project.  I had to say at 2.21.0 .  Not sure why.   Otherwise I was getting a compile error: something about Reflection api.