# maven surefire plugin not using --enable-preview mode

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, java-13

Here it's my pom.xml:

```
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>13</source>
                <target>13</target>
                <release>13</release>
                <compilerArgs>
                    --enable-preview
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is that the build goes ok, but when tests are launched I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test
>   (default-test) on project foo-project: Execution default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test failed:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not
>   enabled for it/project/MyTest (class file version 57.65535). Try
>   running with '--enable-preview' -> [Help 1]

What I have to insert in pom.xml for executing tests with enabled preview mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55311987

Comment: Isn't it strange that the version of surefire in pom.xml is 2.22.2 whereas the one in the log is 3.0.0-M4?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

- Maven Version: 3.8.1
- Surefire Version: 2.22.2
- JK: 13

I used `<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>` and it worked fine.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${java.version}</release>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>-Xlint:unchecked,deprecation</compilerArg>
                    <compilerArg>--enable-preview</compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```