# Enable-preview with maven and junit

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml

I'm writing some Java code using pattern-matching switch, which requires `--enable-preview` to be set in several contexts (compiler, runtime, IDE). At this point, I've got all except one of them: unit tests.

I have these in `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>18</source>
      <target>18</target>
      <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and Maven successfully enables preview for the compiler, but not the unit tests. How do I enable it for junit?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the surefire plugin? See suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303837/problem-running-tests-with-enabled-preview-features-in-surefire-and-failsafe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044079/maven-surefire-plugin-not-using-enable-preview-mode

Answer (score 1):

First you should upgrade the plugin version to the most recent version 3.12.1 as well as for maven-surefire-plugin (3.2.3):

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
          <compilerArg>--enable-preview</compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

*Update*

The configuration for the maven-compiler-plugin can be simplified like this:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <enablePreview>true</enablePreview>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

- Documentation for [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) and also explicit the docs for [args.](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine)
- Documentation for the [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) and also explict the reference for [compilerArgs.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs)

Check the current available versions of plugins:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: can you point the official documentation, that would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @ChristophHenrici Added doc references...